# Inconsistent accessibility: base class is less accessible than class

Tags: c#, dll, access-specifier

So I have an abstract base class in a DLL and child classes of that class. I want the childs to be public, but the base to be private so that it cannot be accessed outside of the dll.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 37):

You don't and you can't.

If you want to expose the class as `public`, the base-type **must** be `public`. One other option is to have a `public interface`, and only expose the type via the `interface` (presumably with a factory method somewhere for creating instances).

One final option is to *encapsulate* the base-class rather than inherit it.

Comment: Or all the methods/properties on the base class to be protected? but the class itself to be public?

Comment: @Liam that depends what you're trying to protect against; for example, if someone external can *subclass* it, they have access to those methods anyway.

Comment: @Liam yes, `internal` would prevent external people from getting easy access; of course, with reflection they can do most things anyway.

Answer (score 19):

Make it `public`, make all constructors `internal` (if you're using the default constructor, add a parameterless constructor to override that).

Then while public and not sealed, it can't be sub-classed by external code.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify what I was saying in comments on @Marc Gravel's answer you *could*

```
public ChildClass : ParentClass
{

}

public ParentClass
{
   internal void MethodIdontWantToExpose()
  {

  }

}
```

That said an `interface` is probably the best solution